# how to set dynamic height in class:before using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to set screen height to my class :before ? i tired to do this using jquery.
here is my code:

```
var login_height = $(window).height();     
$(".login_left_box:before").css('border-bottom-width' , login_height+"px");
```

and here i set dynamic border-bottom-width: **1024px** in this class(set 1024px dynamic) so how can i ?

```
.login_left_box:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 750px solid #fff;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/common/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom-width: 1024px;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i was solved this problem

set height **100vh**

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't do this, a `:before` element is not a DOM object.

What you can do is this :

```
var login_height = $(window).height();     
$("<div class='before'></div>")
    .css('border-bottom-width' , login_height+"px")
    .prependTo($(".login_left_box"));
```

And, in your CSS :

```
.login_left_box>.before {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 750px solid #fff;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/common/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom-width: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: You can indirectly affect non DOM elements via js - you can create dynamic `<style></style>`, that would override the pseudo-element's properties.